# Como chamar uma função on change já declarada

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho um radio, que muda os input de acordo com o radio selecionado, porém gostaria que ele viesse selecionado assim que eu carregasse a pagina de acordo com o valor da session que eu passo para a pagina html. Estou fazendo o change nos radios e fazendo trigger change porém ele não funciona, segue o código a baixo.

HTML

```
<div class="divRadio">
     <input type="radio" name="porcentagemRadio" id="1" class="pg porcentagemRadio" value="1"/> Porcentagem
     <input type="radio" name="porcentagemRadio" id="2" class="pg porcentagemRadio" value="2"/> Valor absoluto
</div>
<div class="divPorcentagem"  id="porcentagem2">
     <label class="control-label porcentagem" for="porcentagem">Porcentagem: </label>
     <select name="porcentagem" id="porcentagemSelect" class="form-control porcent">
           <option value="">Selecione a Porcentagem</option>
           <option value="20">20%</option>
           <option value="10">10%</option>
           <option value="15">15%</option>
           <option value="30">30%</option>
           <option value="35">35%</option>
           <option value="40">40%</option>
           <option value="45">45%</option>
           <option value="50">50%</option>
     </select>
</div>
<div id="precoAbsoluto" class="divAbsoluto">
     <label for="preco2" class="control-label">Preço: </label>
     <input type="number" name="preco2" id="preco1" class="form-control absoluto">              
</div>
<div id="precoAbsoluto2" class="divAbsoluto2">
    <label for="preco" class="control-label">Preço: </label>
    <input type="number" name="preco" id="preco" readonly="true" class="form-control absoluto2">
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#porcentagem2").hide();
    $("#precoAbsoluto").hide();    
    $("#precoAbsoluto2").hide();    
    $('.porcentagemRadio').on('change',function () {
        $("#preco1").val("");
        $("#preco").val("");
        if($(this).val() === '1'){
            $("#porcentagem2").show();
            $("#precoAbsoluto").hide();
            $("#precoAbsoluto2").show();
        }
        if($(this).val() === '2'){
            $("#porcentagem2").hide();
            $("#precoAbsoluto").show();
            $("#precoAbsoluto2").

    document.getElementById(<?php echo $_SESSION['porcentagemRadio']; ?>).checked =  true;
    $(".porcentagemRadio").trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui faltou colocar `.hide()`:

```
$("#precoAbsoluto2").????
```

E faltou também fechar o segundo if com `}`.

Outra coisa é que faltaram as aspas para delimitar a variável do PHP em:

```
document.getElementById(<?php echo $_SESSION['porcentagemRadio']; ?>).checked =  true;
```

Seria:

```
document.getElementById('<?php echo $_SESSION['porcentagemRadio']; ?>').checked = true; 
                        ↑                                            ↑
```

Outro problema é que o evento change aponta para todos os elementos com a classe `.porcentagemRadio`. Ao disparar o trigger, irá chamar o evento o número de vezes igual à quantidade de elementos que possuem a classe `.porcentagemRadio`, ou seja, duas vezes.

O certo é disparar o change apenas no elemento checado. É só acrescentar no seletor o `:checked` que irá disparar o change apenas no elemento checado:

```
$(".porcentagemRadio:checked").trigger("change");
                        ↑
```

Veja:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#porcentagem2").hide();
    $("#precoAbsoluto").hide();    
    $("#precoAbsoluto2").hide();    
    $('.porcentagemRadio').on('change',function () {
        $("#preco1").val("");
        $("#preco").val("");
        if($(this).val() === '1'){
            $("#porcentagem2").show();
            $("#precoAbsoluto").hide();
            $("#precoAbsoluto2").show();
        }
        if($(this).val() === '2'){
            $("#porcentagem2").hide();
            $("#precoAbsoluto").show();
            $("#precoAbsoluto2").hide();
        }
        });
    document.getElementById('1').checked =  true;
    $(".porcentagemRadio:checked").trigger("change");

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divRadio">
     <input type="radio" name="porcentagemRadio" id="1" class="pg porcentagemRadio" value="1"/> Porcentagem
     <input type="radio" name="porcentagemRadio" id="2" class="pg porcentagemRadio" value="2"/> Valor absoluto
</div>
<div class="divPorcentagem"  id="porcentagem2">
     <label class="control-label porcentagem" for="porcentagem">Porcentagem: </label>
     <select name="porcentagem" id="porcentagemSelect" class="form-control porcent">
           <option value="">Selecione a Porcentagem</option>
           <option value="20">20%</option>
           <option value="10">10%</option>
           <option value="15">15%</option>
           <option value="30">30%</option>
           <option value="35">35%</option>
           <option value="40">40%</option>
           <option value="45">45%</option>
           <option value="50">50%</option>
     </select>
</div>
<div id="precoAbsoluto" class="divAbsoluto">
     <label for="preco2" class="control-label">Preço: </label>
     <input type="number" name="preco2" id="preco1" class="form-control absoluto">              
</div>
<div id="precoAbsoluto2" class="divAbsoluto2">
    <label for="preco" class="control-label">Preço: </label>
    <input type="number" name="preco" id="preco" readonly class="form-control absoluto2">
</div>
```

> Uma obs.: Não é muito recomendado usar números como `id` de elementos,
>   como informa [esta documentação MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) sobre o atributo `id`.

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda, realmente funcionou e desculpe me pelos erros, como não mandei código inteiro acabei enviando sem algumas partes sem querer, mas muito obrigada!